# React + Redux Login

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, jwt

I'm finding a problem that I can not find an optimal solution,

Well, the problem involves Redux, when making a request in the Login route, to receive the Token. The middleware that will handle the result of the request always returns with payload = undefined.

If I make any promises using this middleware, it usually returns the result, but when it is login, it tries to do SET before receiving the result.

middleware: https://textuploader.com/dnp0m

Reducer Auth: https://textuploader.com/dnp0q

Reducer Common: https://textuploader.com/dnp0c

Agent: https://textuploader.com/dnp0l

Im Calling the dispatch like this

```
onSubmit: (cpf, pass) => {
    dispatch({type: LOGIN, payload: agent.Auth.login(cpf, pass)})
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be in your middleware, when you look at middleware code you are updating the action.payload object itself.

```
        res => {
            console.log('RESULT', res);
            action.payload = res;
            store.dispatch({ type: ASYNC_END, promise: action.payload });
            store.dispatch(action);
        }
```

instead of updating action.payload value, just send the res value.

```
       res => {
            console.log('RESULT', res);
            store.dispatch({ type: ASYNC_END, promise: res });
            store.dispatch(action);
        }
```

Comment: I've saw a code exactly like this working, I'm doing something wrong I guess https://github.com/gothinkster/react-redux-realworld-example-app